# Failover Database Server for each DB vs for each service application

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, service-application, failover

Our SP2010 farm have 1 SQL server (sql01). Recently we setup another sql server (sql02) with SQL mirroring. I follow this [blog post](http://www.toddklindt.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=202) to setup failover server for each database (including system db and content db) with PowerShell.

Later I found several service application also have "Failover Database Server" settings. For example, managed metadata and secure store:
[image]

My question is, do I need to setup both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The blog reference in my question have a typo in the PowerShell. The blog used:

```
$db = Get-SPDatabase | Where-Object { $_.TypeName -eq "Configuration Database" }
$db.AddFailoverServiceInstance("sql02")
$db.update
```

Afterward, I run this command to verify:

```
Get-SPDatabase | select name, failoverserver, type | sort name | ft -auto | Out-String -Width 2000
```

The result shows all databases have been updated with failover server. However, in fact, the last line should be **$db.update()** (add the blanket). Without the blanket, the update is in temporary stage only.

Answer (score 1):

Once you configured the mirroring on SQL server side and your services databases are part of it then you have to configure this settings. Once you have this setting then SharePoint will automatically try to connect to failed over server in case of primary failure.

> Prior to configuring a database for database mirroring with SharePoint
>   Server 2010 the database should first be configured for database
>   mirroring on the SQL Server.

Read this Bill Bear post for complete understanding. [Database Mirroring in SharePoint 2010](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/wbaer/2010/05/03/database-mirroring-in-sharepoint-2010/)

Comment: In Bill's post, he doesn't mention how to configure failover db server for config database. I think the only way is perform the setup by powershell. However, the failover is not automatically. In my test, I have to setup SQL alias (sql01 > sql02) in order to work around it. Not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

You can run **Get-SPDatabase GUID | select name, failoverserver** command to verify if the db have setting up the failover server . If not , you can configure  via PowerShell **or** Central Admin . But powershell is a recommended approach .

From your screenshot , if you want to create a new service application (Managed Metadata Service application in this case) and want to use a new DB , you need to fill in the failover server name , but if you want to use the existing DB which have been set up failover database , you needn't fill this box in this page .