# Sharepoint Failover Setting

Tags: failover

How can i update failover server with management shell permanently?

I have executed the following command in management shell:

```
Get-SPDatabase | Select Name,Server,failoverserver
$db = Get-SPDatabase 
$db.AddFailoverServiceInstance("10.12.10.10")
$db.update
```

It seems nothing happen after restart the sharepoint server. It seems execute temporarily in the management shell.

Comment: You need to use a NetBIOS or FQDN, not IP address. Is there a reason you're using SQL Mirroring instead of SQL Always On? Mirroring is a deprecated technology.

Comment: @TrevorSeward reasons for SQL mirroring?  Using std edition and don’t want to set up shared storage for Always On Failover Clustering is one I can come up with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code,

```
$db = Get-SPDatabase | Where-Object { $_.TypeName -eq "Configuration Database" }
$db.AddFailoverServiceInstance("10.12.10.10")
$db.update()

Get-SPDatabase | select name, failoverserver, type | sort name | ft -auto | Out-String -Width 2000
```

The result shows all databases have been updated with failover server. However, in fact, the last line should be **$db.update()** (add the blanket). Without the blanket, the update is in temporary stage only.

[SOURCE](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/232717/failover-database-server-for-each-db-vs-for-each-service-application)

Comment: Did this help you?? Or still with the error??

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: If my answer is useful, kindly upvote and Mark it as answer, so that it will be helpful for others too.

Comment: I have upvoted but i don't know how to mark it as answer.

Comment: Thanks for upvoting, Refer this link to know how to mark it answer, https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work